# How to speed up Pandas loops

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

This code loops over a giant dataframe consisting of ~14 million rows, where each row is a published article. Our goal is to look at each keyword in `all_keywords` (which has ~400 keywords), and find the dates the keyword first and last appeared.

```
ranges = {}
for dk in all_keywords:
    dk_df = df.loc[[(dk in map(str.lower, x)) for x in df['keywords']]]
    first_appearance = dk_df['date'].iloc[0].strftime('%Y')
    last_appearance = dk_df['date'].iloc[-1].strftime('%Y')
    ranges[dk] = [first_appearance, last_appearance]
```

The problem is that this code is so SLOW. It takes hours.

How can it be faster?

I suspect the problem is either with looping through each keyword, or with mapping all the keywords against each array in `df['keywords']`.

Comment: share sample data with expected output

Comment: Use `df["column"].str.contains("|".join(list_of_keywords))` to lookup a whole column instead of looping.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it without sample data, in general bare loops are not how use Dataframes. In your case, `groupby` to select each key should be much more performant.

```
df.groupby('keywords').first()['date']
df.groupby('keywords').last()['date']
```

Comment: Thanks! Each cell in 'keywords' is actually an array. Probably would be best to split it out?

Comment: Either that or you could convert them to tuples. You need something hashable for that to work.